# Elasticsearch full match score lower than part prefix

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I use text field and default analyzer.

Source:

```
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Nette"  // convert by default analyzer to 'nette'
  
  "id": "2",
  "name": ".NET"  // convert by default analyzer to 'net'
```

I do phrase_prefix query

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "query": ".net", // convert by default analyzer to 'net'
            "fields": ["name"]
        }
}
```

And i get result:

```
"_score": 8.211289,
    "_source": { "name": "Nette",

"_score": 7.5605545,
    "_source": { "name": ".NET",
```

What is joke?
why full match 'net' == 'net'  is lower then 'net' == 'nette' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `explain: true` query parameter to find out the details of the score value. I'm not sure, but it might be that the found word is just longer than the other one and therefore "more valuable".

Comment: That is, by default, es calculates the score for the entire document, and not just for the fields that i specified? if so , how do I tell ES to calculate the score only for the fields I 'm looking for ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to change the scoring behaviour itself. If it is crucial to get that exact match with higher score, I would modify the search instead. You could use e.g. function score or other compound queries to boost certain results or make two separate queries by using multi search. In multi search you can retrieve exact matches with one query and the prefix matches with another one within the same request.